# In SSMS how do I select for each unique value in one column a missing value in a second column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I write the T-SQL code to select only one encounter row where there is no `Form D` listed in the `Document` column?

The `Encounter` column is from `Table 1` and the `Document` column is from `Table 2`.

My output would then just list the following encounters with no `Form D`, (either `NULL` or it didn't have a `Form D`):

```
Encounter
---------
1002
1004
1005
1007
1008
1009

SELECT 
    T1.Encounter,
    T2.Forms
FROM
    Table_One T1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    T1.encounter_ID ON Forms.encounter_ID T2
ORDER BY 
    encounter, forms
```

[image: Data Example]

Comment: So you have two tables with one column each that you join with a mysterious syntax: `ON Forms.encounter_ID T2`. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
    T1.Encounter,     
    T2.Forms   
FROM Table_One T1  LEFT JOIN  T1.encounter_ID ON Forms.encounter_ID T2  
WHERE T2.Forms IS NULL OR T2.Forms = 'Form D' 
GROUP BY encounter, forms
```